# How to remove <div> distortions in background image

Tags: html, css

In CSS & HTML, how do I avoid the distortions in the background image when i scroll down?

The outline for my code is as below : HTML

```css
* {
      margin : 0;
      background-image : url("images/background_6.jpg");
      color : lightgrey;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <header>
            <h1> Heading ONE </h1>
            <h2> Something Else </h2>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <a href=""> Home </a>
            <a href=""> Something </a>
            <a href=""> Something else </a>
        </nav>

        <section>
            <p> this section is for one paragraph</p>
        </section>

        <section>
            <p> this section is for one paragraph </p>
            </secton>

            <section>
                <p> this section is for one paragraph </p>
                </secton>

                <section>
                    <p> this section is for one paragraph </p>
                    </secton>
    </div>
</body>
```

I need to get rid of the distortions in each  or more accurately each block.

[Here's the image of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNOHj.jpg)

Comment: Please add a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: replace `*` with `body` and add `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you add to every element on the page the background image, also the `sections`. The result is the "distortions".

```css
body{
margin : 0;
background-image : url("images/background_6.jpg");
background-repeat: none;
color : lightgrey;
}
```

If you want for your header a seperate image do something like this:

```css
   body{
    margin : 0;
    background-image : url("images/background-body.jpg");
    background-repeat: none;
    color : lightgrey;
    }
    
       header{
    margin : 0;
    background-image : url("images/background-header.jpg");
    background-repeat: none;
    color : lightgrey;
    }
```

Comment: You can mark my anwser as "solution", there is no "close" button.